# React Router doesn't display component when route is matched (but render works)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I am trying to learn `React` and using `Create-React-App` to experiment.

Today I was trying to learn how to use `React Router`, but I couldn't make it work.

Here is my code: (`App.js`)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import { Navbar, Jumbotron, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const baseUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">React Star Wars Table Test</h1>
        </header>

        <Router>
          <div>
            <NavLink to={baseUrl + '/Foo'}>Foo</NavLink>  <NavLink to={'/Bar'}>Bar</NavLink>
            <hr />


            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact render={() => (<h1>HOME</h1>)} />

              <Route path={baseUrl + "/Foo"} exact Component={Foo} />
              <Route path='/Bar' exact Component={Bar} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }



}

class Foo extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <p>Foo!</p>
    );
  }
}

class Bar extends Component {
  retnder(){
    return (
        <h1>Bar!</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**The issue is that the routes don't display the components when they match the URL (either clicking on the NavLinks or manually typing the URL).**

The base ('/') route works and displays the HOME H1.

I know the routes are matching because if I try to use the `render` attribute for all the routes, it works.

- No compile errors, no console errors.
- The sample code contains the `Switch` tag, but I have tried also
  without, same result.
- The sample code has a `NavLink` and a `Route` with
  a baseUrl const and one without, I have tried either way (none, both,
  one yes and one not), same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prop of `Route` that takes a component is called `component`, not `Component` with a capital `c`.

```
<Route path='/Bar' exact component={Bar} />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thanks a lot, I still have to get used to the notation and naming conventions.

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano Awesome! You're welcome. Yeah, it's quite a common error.